# How to implement simple request-reponse techique without pitfalls

Tags: python, c++, sockets, network-programming, boost-asio

I want to create simple client and server that should work by the request-response principle like this:

- client send the following string: "do_some_stuff"
- server do the appropriate actions and send the following string as a response: "success"
- client read the response and do some logging stuff
- after some time client send new command and all actions repeat again

Sounds easy? Unfortunately, I have the following questions:

- Which technique should I use to read responses? Should I read data until some specific characters sequence occurred or should I just call the `read` function in some kind of `while true` loop and wait for the connection close (I am going to close socket on the server side after response sending)?
- I can't get why there is so many examples that just read some amount of bytes (for example, 1024) and hope that the answer will be read completely? Why libraries decide that there is no further bytes after "success" if we said that we should get 1024 bytes? Because of the connection closing on the server side?
- What if `read_until` will never be able to get the terminating characters sequence (for example, because of the internet connection)? Will it wait indefinitely?

All in all, is it ok do to smth like this?

**Client**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), "127.0.0.1", "5013");
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket s(io_service);
    boost::asio::connect(s, iterator);

    boost::asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream request_stream(&request);
    request_stream << "do_some_stuff\n";

    boost::asio::write(s, request);

    boost::asio::streambuf b;
    boost::asio::read_until(s, b, '\n');
    std::istream is(&b);
    std::string line;
    std::getline(is, line);

    std::cout << "Reply is: " << line << std::endl;
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }
}
```

**Server**

```
import socket
import threading

def main():
    listener = socket.socket()
    listener.bind(('127.0.0.1', 5013))
    listener.listen(5)
    while True:
        client, _ = listener.accept()
        worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(client,))
        worker_thread.setDaemon(True)
        worker_thread.start()

def worker(client):
    data = ""
    while True:
        packet = client.recv(1024)
        if not packet:
            break

        data += packet

        if '\n' in data:
            line, data = data.split('\n', 1)
            print line
            client.sendall('success\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is there smth wrong with this solution? By the way, why `client.recv(1024)` here finishes before receiving 1024 bytes from the socket? How does it know that there is no data after it? How does it actually work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The most used way is using a header that specifies a length and read
  until all the bytes are received.  Using a message separator is also
  used a lot.  Waiting for connection ends can be done for connectionless
  communication which means, setting up a connection, sending a message 
  (and reply) and closing for each message, which is less efficient.
- Using one read to get all the bytes for a tcp message is a common
  mistake that normally always works for short messages.  The mistake
  is that tcp is a streaming protocol, not a message protocol. 
  However, tcp is mostly used for passing messages.  The length
  parameter should be the size of the buffer, not the expected number
  of bytes. The reader knows when it can return because the sender
  sends packets.
- When a connection is lost without the chance to notify (e.g. power
  off, cable disconnect), this can lead to endless waiting.  A possible
  solution to that is [tcp_keepalive](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setsockopt).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! So, my code should work correctly in all cases, am I right?

Comment: No guarantees without testing, but it looks good enough to me.

Comment: Thanks! And how `client.recv(1024)` decides when to end read data?

Comment: Based on the packets that are sent over tcp

Comment: I didn't understand you correctly. For example, I sent a string "do_some_stuff\n" and this string was wrapped in one packet only (14 bytes). Why `client.recv(1024)` decides that there's no data further and it should return these 14 bytes without waiting for another packets?

Comment: That is up to the TCP layer. It can decide based on incomplete mtu packets or timeout on the next packet.